# Chebyshev Equioscillation Theorem in presence of extra conditions

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, approximation-theory

Let $P_\ell$ be polynomials of degree $\ell$. For $f \in C[0,1]$, define the minimax error $E_\ell(f) = \min_{p \in P_\ell} \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x) - p(x)|$. We know that for the above scenario the best minimax approximating polynomial $q$ is unique and $q$ satisfies the equioscillation property. I want to know what is known when one adds some extra conditions, for example consider the following situations:

- Let $Q$ be the set of odd polynomials. Define $E^{(Q)}_\ell(f) = \min_{p \in P_\ell \cap Q} \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x) - p(x)|$.
- Let $R$ be the set of polynomials so that $p(0)=f(0)$ and $p(1)=f(1)$. Define $E^{(R)}_\ell(f) = \min_{p \in P_\ell \cap R} \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x) - p(x)|$.

In both the above cases, is there an equioscillation theorem analog, and is the approximating polynomial unique? If not, what are counterexamples?